# Stopping the build Xamarin Android project while dotfuscator run

Tags: obfuscation, dotfuscator

I try to integrate Dotfuscator in my Xamarin Project according this manual : https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/getting_started_xamarin.html

I executed steps : `Import the Targets File` and `Set MSBuild Properties` and I skipped `Add Dotfuscator Config File to Project` because I have not config as yet. Then I launch building and got this error :

`There are no assemblies to process.  Stopping the build...`
[image]

Looks like dotfuscator required .dll assemblies but I don't have these, because building is not completed, because dotfuscator is stoping.

**UPD**

I Edited Android.csproj file like this :

1) added

> < DotfuscatorXamarinEnabled >true< /DotfuscatorXamarinEnabled >

2) added this Code

```
< PropertyGroup > 
< DotfuscatorXamarinConfigFileName >DotfuscatorConfig.xml< /DotfuscatorXamarinConfigFileName >
< DotfuscatorXamarinCliPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\PreEmptive Solutions\Dotfuscator Professional Edition Evaluation4.43.1\dotfuscator.exe< /DotfuscatorXamarinCliPath >
< DotfuscatorXamarinGenerateNewConfigFile >true< /DotfuscatorXamarinGenerateNewConfigFile>
< DotfuscatorIncludeAsInput >< /DotfuscatorIncludeAsInput>   
< /PropertyGroup>   
< Import Project="..\..\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin.targets"/>
```

before `< /Project>` tag.

[image]

and still have the error : `There are no assemblies to process.  Stopping the build...`

**UPD2**

I tried to change .csproj file exactly like at this link :: [https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/getting_started_protect.html#integrate-xamarin](http://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/getting_started_protect.html#integrate-xamarin)

[image]

this time obfuscation not even started. Application was builded,  but it was simple apk, as usually.

Comment: In response to Update #2, you're almost there. You still need to change the `Project` that is in your `<Import>` tag; it is still using the Xamarin-specific Dotfuscator Community targets file, not the Dotfuscator Professional targets file, which covers Xamarin and many other kinds of projects. So it should instead be `<Import Project="$(DotfuscatorMSBuildDir)\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Common.targets" />`.

Comment: @JoeSewell if I try to replace `<Import Project="..\..\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin.targets"/>` to this `<Import Project="$(DotfuscatorMSBuildDir)\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Common.targets" />` obfuscation not started - I just build app without obfuscation.

Comment: @JoeSewell ok, looks like I have mistake in path to `targets`. Now building process is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link is to the Dotfuscator Community (CE) user guide, but your screenshot shows you are using Dotfuscator Professional. Instead, see the [Xamarin page](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/getting_started_xamarin.html) in the Dotfuscator Professional user guide.

(Note: I work on the Dotfuscator team.)

Comment: @Сергей The sentence you mention is on the page for the older Visual Studio integration, which is deprecated and doesn't work with Xamarin projects. Please read the page I linked to, which will direct you to the [Protect Your App](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/getting_started_protect.html) page, which explains how to use the new integration. In the new integration, Dotfuscator will automatically protect assemblies whenever you build the Xamarin project in Visual Studio.

Comment: So, can I start build  after I added my Android project to Output ? like this https://imgur.com/a/y4DFQ1a

Comment: @Сергей Again, that screenshot is from the older Visual Studio integration, which does not work with Xamarin. Instead, follow the directions on the [Protect Your App](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/getting_started_protect.html) page. This will not require a separate "Dotfuscator project" - Dotfuscator will just run whenever you build your original Xamarin.Android project, and protect the assemblies automatically before the build packages the assemblies into an `.apk` file.

Comment: @Сергей Yes, that is the link I posted in the answer.

Comment: Looks like I already did all these steps, according Dotfuscator Community user guide. I mean I just edited .csproj file

Comment: let me explain what I exactly did.

Comment: **The instructions for Community and Professional are different.** I know they both involve editing the project file, but they are different. At this point, I think it would be more efficient for you to [contact our support team](https://www.preemptive.com/contact/supportrequestform), which you can do even when evaluating Dotfuscator Professional. Stack Overflow comments aren't the best place for a walk-through.

Comment: I contacted to your support team 5 hours ago, and still have no answer.